# Is there a way to configure PuTTY or other terminal to flash the taskbar on next output to stdout?

Tags: notifications, terminal, stdout, taskbar, putty

I'm specifically looking for a solution for PuTTY but also interested for other terminal emulators, like Gnome Terminal.

My thought is it would be useful if I start a `tar zxvf` to be able to set a trigger on the terminal emulator, minimize it, and on next output to stdout/stderr I get a notification in the task bar that the command has finished.

Answer (score 12):

This works for me:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

Then update your PuTTY session to use the Visual Bell, and set "Taskbar/caption indication on bell" to Flashing or Steady.

Then run this command after your tar completes:

```
tar xvzf file ; echo -e "\a"
```

Here is a screenshot: Save these settings as the default settings and/or the sessions' settings you have
[image: PuTTY Configuration]

Comment: Interesting solution, unfortunate that you have to append the dummy echo to every command though :/