# Is there a way to make the taskbar blink from the terminal?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, gnome

I like to let my builds run in the background while I continue problem solving my code, but I find it annoying to not know when my build has finished. I already know how to play a sound after a build is done, but was wondering if there is another way to approach this problem.

Is it possible to make the taskbar blink from the terminal? That way I could use it at the end of my build scripts and I would get a friendly blinking task bar icon to alert me.

Desktop environment is gnome

Comment: What desktop environment? (gnome? KDE? xfce?)

Comment: Oh good point. It is gnome.

Comment: Best to put that in to the question and add a `gnome` tag, as this will be specific to that WM.

Comment: Definitely specific to the WM/DE... For example, I don't have a taskbar usually because I use Window Maker most of the time.

Comment: It's actually a lot less WM-specific than you think; all of them use the same hint to cause this. The trick is finding the correct window to set the hint on.

Comment: http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html

Comment: Instead of flashing an existing window, you could create a dummy application which does essentially nothing but requesting a hint, for instance using `gtk_window_set_urgency_hint()` in GTK.

Comment: My way to deal with this - pipe your build output to the mail command and send this to the TXT gateway email for my cellphone - <my-number>@vtext.com for Verizon - I'm sure the other providers have something similar.  If you are interested in this approach, I can share my shell script which helps with this.

Comment: That is really slick!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to configure PuTTY or other terminal to flash the taskbar on next output to stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878925/is-there-a-way-to-configure-putty-or-other-terminal-to-flash-the-taskbar-on-next)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/02/utilising-the-notification-system-in-kde-or-gnome-in-bash-scripts-ubuntu-9-10-linux/

For gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

then

```
notify-send "notification title" "notification text"
```

From my testing, supplying `-u critical` seems to give it an infinite timeout.

Comment: +1 for going above and beyond! Thank you so much!

Comment: This works for me as well with Linux Mint XFCE and I didn't need to install anything